# How to rotate a matrix in J?

Tags: j

Imagine a matrix with rank 2. I want to rotate this so that the rows become columns and vice versa. I've been able to do this with `,./,."1`, but I'm not sure that's the most idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: You are searching for [transpose `|:`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d232.htm)

Comment: Not sure how I missed `|:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the transpose function: `|:`

You can read all about it at  http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help802/dictionary/d232.htm